# Primefaces 3.5 AutoComplete not working with Liferay 6.1 GA2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete, liferay-6

I am using **Liferay 6.1 GA2** with JSF 2.0 (**liferay faces 3.1.2-ga3**, **mojarra 2.1.21**, and **primefaces 3.5**). I am trying to implement an autocomplete field (multiple) but it's not working. The complete method in the backing bean is not being called.

However, if I make use of a single simple autocomplete field with a dropdown, the complete method in my bean does get called on button click, with an empty query passed into the method.

My codes are below:

**content.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:aui="http://liferay.com/faces/aui"
    xmlns:aui-cc="http://liferay.com/faces/aui-cc"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
    xmlns:bridge="http://portletfaces.org/bridge"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

    version="2.1">

    <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content-placeholder">
            <div class="tab_main_content">
                <aui:layout>
                        <p:autoComplete id="to" name="to" value="#{myBean.to}" completeMethod="#{myBean.getUsers}" multiple="true"/> 
                </aui:layout>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</f:view>
```

**template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:aui="http://liferay.com/faces/aui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
    xmlns:liferay-ui="http://liferay.com/faces/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

    version="2.1">

    <div id="msgPortletDiv" class="gray_box3">
        <h:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- INSERT: For content -->
            <ui:insert name="content-placeholder">
                    placeholder text
            </ui:insert>
        </h:form>
    </div>  
</f:view>
```

**complete method from backing bean (getUsers) and 'to' attribute**

```
private List<String> to = new ArrayList<String>();

// Autocomplete method
public List<String> getUsers(String query) {  
    _log.info("getUsers() method in myBean for query: " + query);
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    return results;  
}  

//Getter and setter for 'to'
public List<String> getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(List<String> to) {
    this.to = to;
}
```

I'm not sure if there's some compatibility issue or if I'm just doing something wrong. I can't seem to find any demos online for primefaces' autoComplete with liferay.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

** **EDIT**: For the sake of troubleshooting, I have tried to simplify my content.xhtml and not use template.xhtml, but it still doesn't trigger the backing bean method. As earlier, the simple dropdown version onclick works with this, but not the ajax call of the non-dropdown autocomplete fields.

**Simplified content.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

    version="2.1">
    <h:form>
        <div class="tab_main_content message-body">
            <p:autoComplete id="to" name="to" value="#{myBean.to}" completeMethod="#{myBean.getUsers}" multiple="true"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Comment: If you remove <aui:layout> does it work then?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't... I have changed my code in content.xhtml to remove the use of template.xhtml and aui:layout but it still doesn't trigger the backing bean method.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is almost right. But you need to change one thing in your backing bean. You say drop-down works fine. So selecting 1 user is no problem. If in your backing bean `#{myBean.to}` is defined like `private User to` this works good for one selection because it can hold 1 instance of User.

If you change this to `private List<User> to`  You can hold multiple instances of users in your list. Don't forget to add the getters and setters and you're good to go

Comment: I do have the getter and setter in my backing bean (sorry I did not include them earlier). I have included that code in my question now.

For clarification, for a single selection, if I do not use dropdown="true", it does not work either. It seems as though it's the textbox onchange ajax call that has an issue. The call to the backing bean complete method only works when  I manually click the dropdown button.

Comment: What do you see if you debug the requests with firebug?

Comment: Oh gosh, I should have done that ages ago! After turning on firebug and using that (I was using chrome before and that wasn't very helpful), I got this error: TypeError: $.ui is undefined. I included the jquery-ui js and the complete method is getting triggered now. Thank you so much for giving me a push in the right direction!